# Image Merging Code cuts of Bottom of the Image

Tags: java, image, android-studio

I Have some code that Puts to Images next to one another vertically. But it cuts off the bottom of the last image. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
    private Bitmap mergeMultiple(ArrayList<Bitmap> parts) {

    int w = 0, h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
        if (i < parts.size() - 1) {
            w = parts.get(i).getWidth() > parts.get(i + 1).getWidth() ? parts.get(i).getWidth() : parts.get(i + 1).getWidth();
        }
        h += parts.get(i).getHeight();
    }

    Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(temp);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    int top = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {

        top = (i == 0 ? 0 : top + parts.get(i).getHeight() + 100);
        canvas.drawBitmap(parts.get(i), 0f, top, paint);
    }
    return temp;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Simple Fix, Not sure if it was the Best solution However. I had to put a +100 after `h += parts.get(i).getHeight()`